# Accessing ext3 / ext4 journals

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3, ext4, journaling

ext3 and ext4 file systems have journaling. Is there any chance there's some API to get details or events about files?

Some kind of API that will allow a user space program to access journal entries for files. Or even journal events, like "file x was deleted".

This seems to be [some kind of documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) but I'm not sure if it's the right stuff.

Comment: Probably, however what do you mean by 'history'? I suspect you are overestimating just what gets journaled, and how that journal gets flushed.

Comment: You are confusing [journaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_filesystem) with [versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_filesystem) filesystems.

Comment: 'Journal' mode of journaling in ext3 saves data and metadata to journal. So accessing transaction in journal can give us the version of file.

Comment: The question is sound, however you want to use the journal metadata, is there a an api or sys calls to access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## With [`debugfs`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html)

### `logdump`

You can display information about the file system journal with the `logdump` command from `debugfs`.

For example, `sudo debugfs -R 'logdump -S' /dev/sda3` yields

```
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke journal_checksum_v3
Total journal size:       512M
Total journal blocks:     131072
Max transaction length:   131072
Fast commit length:       0
Journal sequence:         0x004bd0ae
Journal start:            109412
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0x157eebb7

Journal starts at block 109412, transaction 4968622
Found expected sequence 4968622, type 5 (revoke table) at block 109412
Found expected sequence 4968622, type 1 (descriptor block) at block 109413
Found expected sequence 4968622, type 2 (commit block) at block 109419
Found expected sequence 4968623, type 1 (descriptor block) at block 109420
Found expected sequence 4968623, type 2 (commit block) at block 109422
Found expected sequence 4968624, type 1 (descriptor block) at block 109423
Found expected sequence 4968624, type 2 (commit block) at block 109425
Found expected sequence 4968625, type 1 (descriptor block) at block 109426
// rest omitted
```

I realize that `debugfs` is not an API, but it accesses the journal.

### Read the journal's bytes

To get at the raw bytes of the journal, you can use `debugfs` again. Its `cat` command accepts an inode number and prints the data of the address the inode's pointing to.

Assuming that the journal's inode number is 8:

```
sudo debugfs -R 'cat <8>' /dev/sda3 | hexdump -C
```

This prints the journal's bytes in hexadecimal. You should see the [magic number of the journal's format](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/globals.html#block-header), jbd2, at the beginning:

```
c0 3b 39 98
```

The journal uses [big-endian byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) whereas ext4 uses little-endian.

## With [`jls`](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/man/jls.html)

`jls` from [The Sleuth Kit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sleuth_Kit) also prints information about the journal.

For example, `sudo jls /dev/sda3` yields

```
JBlk    Description
0:  Superblock (seq: 0)
sb version: 4
sb version: 4
sb feature_compat flags 0x00000000
sb feature_incompat flags 0x00000011
        JOURNAL_REVOKE
sb feature_ro_incompat flags 0x00000000
1:  Unallocated Commit Block (seq: 4936768, sec: 1613471034.3277057792)
2:  Unallocated Descriptor Block (seq: 4936769)
3:  Unallocated FS Block 42991838
4:  Unallocated FS Block 0
5:  Unallocated Commit Block (seq: 4949171, sec: 1613574032.1117509120)
6:  Unallocated Descriptor Block (seq: 4949172)
7:  Unallocated Commit Block (seq: 4960433, sec: 1613729975.4288594432)
8:  Unallocated Descriptor Block (seq: 4960434)
// rest omitted
```

The source code of `jls` is [here](https://github.com/sleuthkit/sleuthkit/blob/master/tools/fstools/jls.cpp).

## DIY

Alternatively, you can consult the [ext4 wiki](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/index.html) to parse the journal using a program that you'll have to write yourself. The steps are roughly as follows:

1. Read the ext4 superblock which starts 1024 bytes after the file system.
2. Read the journal inode number from offset 0xE0 of the superblock. The journal's inode number is usually 8. This is documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/globals.html#super-block).
3. Read the data you need from the journal, keep in mind that it's big-endian, as opposed to ext4 being little-endian. The journal's structure is described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/globals.html#journal-jbd2).

Comment: it looks like logdump only works with ext3 but not with ext4,